# Split one single column with periodic repeated headers into two columns (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatable, multiple-columns

I have one single column that looks like this

| None header |
| --- |
| time(s) |
| 0.2055 |
| 0.2302 |
| position(m) |
| 0.4164 |
| 0.4128 |
| time(s) |
| 0.2055 |
| 0.2302 |
| position(m) |
| 0.4164 |
| 0.4128 |

And I want split this column into columns like this:

| time(s) | position(m) |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy reshaping:

```
N = len(df)//4

m = np.tile(np.repeat([False,True], [1,N-1]), len(df)//N)
# array([False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
#        False,  True,  True])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[m, 0]
                     .to_numpy()
                     .reshape((2,-1,N-1))
                     .swapaxes(1,2)
                     .reshape(-1,2),
                   columns=df.iloc[[0,N],0].to_list()
                   )
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  time(s) position(m)
0  0.2055      0.4164
1  0.2302      0.4128
2  0.2055      0.4164
3  0.2302      0.4128
```

Comment: I don't understand the function of swapaxes, I tried this method but I noticed that some data was placed in wrong column.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['g'] = df.index//3%2
temp = df.groupby('g')['header'].apply(list).to_frame().T.explode([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)
temp.columns = temp.iloc[0]
temp[~temp['time(s)'].str.contains('[a-z]')]
```

Output:

```
    time(s) position(m)
1   0.2055  0.4164
2   0.2302  0.4128
4   0.2055  0.4164
5   0.2302  0.4128
```